# Database is slow once in a while

Tags: performance, jboss, oracle11g

I am executing a web service for 100 times. The average response time of this service is 1.5 seconds. But when I look at the response time of each execution individually, there are a few executions (at least 10) which are taking beyond 15 seconds to respond. The data for each request is exactly the same as any previous request (just appending a dynamic number to name...etc).

It certainly looks like a database issue, because my database is responding differently each time we execute a same query again and again. I am not able to understand why my database is behaving like this. My database is oracle 11g. I have experienced this issue with different UI flows as well previously.

Below is the summary of collected metrics

[image]

Comment: Are you running these tests in series or parallel? Are they competing for resources, from a connection pool for example?

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons,

1. check query plan for your query first(how much time it is taking for execution), one reason for slow response some times could be due to caching and after cache entry is old then again it fetching data from DB which is taking time
2. another issue could be filesystem operations/system operations/daemons/some porcesses running in background after specific interval which is making your workflow/webservice execution slow
3. if your workflow involves some write/update operation then disk write operations could be happening for synchronization (internal processing done by database-delayed writes,lazy writes etc)

there can be other reasons also, but check these first. 
check your system logs,database logs,diag logs to find what actaully is happening behind the screen, that will surely tell you where to concentrate.